# Why is one "sent to Coventry"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

I was reading in the paper today of some hapless wight who had been *[sent to Coventry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Send_to_Coventry)* (meaning ostracised and given the silent treatment) by his colleages. It then occurred to me to wonder why *Coventry* should have been chosen for this idiom.

[Phrases](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/sent-to-coventry.html) suggests:-

> The story - and it is no more than that - is that Cromwell sent a
>   group of Royalist soldiers to be imprisoned in Coventry, around 1648.
>   The locals, who were parliamentary supporters, shunned them and
>   refused to consort with them.

[Michael Quinion](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-cov1.htm) also notes:-

> Another story, undated but usually taken to refer to events of a
>   similar period, is that Coventry was strongly opposed to having troops
>   billeted on townspeople, and that soldiers sent there were ostracised
>   by the local population.

but he remarks that

> My own feeling is that neither is convincing, not least because of the
>   century-long gap between Civil War events and the first appearance of
>   the idiom

As neither of thes two things were peculiar to Coventry, I'm also inclined to doubt. Can anyone shed any light on the matter?

Comment: OK, who was the [expletive deleted] who voted to close this as "general reference"?

Comment: yet another (probably incorrect) story about it, relates to taxi companies in London (easy to google).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED has a note

> [The origin of the phrase has been the subject of numerous ingenious conjectures: see Brewer, *Phrase and Fable,* etc. A probable suggestion refers it to the circumstances recorded in quot. 1703; a less likely source has been suggested in quot. *a*1691.]

So they don't know the origin. The citations are:

> [*a*1691   Baxter in *Reliq. Baxt.* i. i. (1696) 44   Thus when I was at Coventry the Religious part of my Neighbours at Kidderminster that would fain have lived quietly at home, were forced..to be gone, and to Coventry they came.
>   1703   *Clarendon's Hist. Rebellion* II. vi. 36   At Bromicham, a Town so generally wicked, that it had risen upon small parties of the Kings, and kill'd, or taken them Prisoners, and sent them to Coventry [then strongly held for the Parliament].]

Both quotations relate a physical sending to Coventry: in the first by driving out from Kidderminster (around 35 miles away); in the second by deporting prisoners there (also around 35 miles, if the place is now West Bromwich). They favour the second, which mirrors what you found in phrases.org.

Comment: Do you happen to know, what "is" the phrase "send to coventry"? Or similar phrases.  It's not really an allusion .. metaphor .. is it just an idiom?  Kind of a command-idiom or verb-idiom or? ... I'm afraid I don't know how to categorise that type of phrase!  Thx